# Salesforce Vlocity, how can I calculate child product quantity based on parent product quantity?

Tags: apex, cpq, vlocity

This
I want to calculate the child product quantity based on the parent quantity and it should look something like this:

**Test case:**

1. Let's take parent quantity is 1. Upon adding child product, default
   quantity is 1 and upon calculating, the child quantity is 1 * 1 = 1.
   Now lets say I want to increase the parent's quantity to 2 - the
   child qunatity should be 1 * 2 = 2.
2. Vice versa, if I change the child's quantity from 1 to 4, the
   calculation should be like 1 * 4 / 2 * 4.

I don't have any screenshots to share that can help really :|.

Is there any resource or a way that I can accomplish this? I was looking into the options, the product structure but there's nothing that will accomplish both cases?

Thank you for the feedback!